# Table content is not displaying in JSP page

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

My project is Spring MVC. In my JSP file the table heading is displaying but displaying any content inside the table that the lists from controller. I have tested the `List`s is accessing from database or not by using jUnit in my Dao file itself. I think something problem with Controller & JSP file.

```
package com.shriram.gaming.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.shriram.gaming.dao.GamerDAO;
import com.shriram.gaming.model.Gamer;

@Controller
public class MainController {
  
  @Autowired
  private GamerDAO gamerDAO;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/")
  public ModelAndView listGamer(ModelAndView model) {
    List<Gamer> listGamer = gamerDAO.list();
//    System.out.println("List of Gamers:"+ listGamer);
    model.addObject("listGamer", listGamer);
    model.setViewName("index");
    
    return model ;
  }
}
```

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Game Manager Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Gamer List</h1>
        ${listGamer}
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>GamerTag</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${listGamer}" var="gamer" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                <td>${gamer.name}</td>
                <td>${gamer.email}</td>
                <td>${gamer.gamertag}</td>
                <td>${gamer.phone}</td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            
        </table>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to display the values of the `Lists<Gamer>` if it holds in the controller. But it doesn't printing anything in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The property for your list is not available in any scope. Trying to print it doesn't do anything, so nothing is displayed. The model is what Spring MVC expected on the view layer, but you didn't add this property to the model. Wrong API usage makes it even  worse. You should start learning scopes of the JSP and how EL expressions search for properties. To add properties to the model you should use something like this

```java
model.addAttribute("listGamer", listGamer);
```

Comment: addAttribute showing error. I think the method should be ModelAndVIew. Could you just me detailed explaination maybe I haven't understood properly

Comment: If it doesn't print anything in the controller then nothing to display in the JSP. The method you use is not important in this case.